# Custom SpnegoAuthenticator worked with Tomcat 8 but gives 404 with Tomcat 9

Tags: java, tomcat, forms-authentication, tomcat9, spnego

Project was developed with Jetty using Form Authentication. File `login.jsp`

```html
<form method="post" action="j_security_check">
    <input type="text" name="j_username"/>
    <input type="password" name="j_password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

In production, it was published in Tomcat 8.0.53 and using a custom `SpnegoAuthenticator` . File `conf/context.xml`

```xml
<Context>
    <Valve className="com.CustomeSpnegoAuthenticator" />
</Context>
```

File `tomcat/application/WEB-INF/web.xml` includes these:

```xml
<login-config>
    <auth-method>SPNEGO</auth-method>
    <realm-name>REALMNAME</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginError.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

in file `CustomeSpnegoAuthenticator.java`, a FormAuthenticator is initialised and set up as below

```java
public class CustomeSpnegoAuthenticator extends org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator {
    private FormAuthenticator formAuthenticator = new FormAuthenticator();
    @Override
    public void setContainer(Container container) {
        try {
            super.setContainer(container);
            formAuthenticator.setContainer(container);
            formAuthenticator.setLandingPage("/home");
            formAuthenticator.start();
            log.info("formAuthenticator state: " + formAuthenticator.getState())
        } catch (LifecycleException ex) {
            log.error("Failed to start authenticators, reason: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected String getAuthMethod() {
        return Constants.SPNEGO_METHOD;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean authenticate(Request request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // process username and password
        // return result
    }
}
```

This worked well in Tomcat 8, authentication happens at `localhost/application/j_security_check` . But after deploying it in Tomcat 9.0.20, it starts giving 404 to `localhost/application/j_security_check`, although in `CustomeSpnegoAuthenticator.java` formAuthenticator's state is `started`. `conf/context.xml`, `conf/web.xml`,`webapps/application/WEB-INF/web.xml` are the same. Only Tomcat version is different.

Does anyone has any idea what might be the reason, or how can I debug further?

Comment: I don't see any SPNEGO involved here.

Answer (score 1):

So after reading the source code, I found the implementation of authenticators in Tomcat 9 is a bit different from Tomcat 8. They replaced `authenticate` with `doAuthenticate`.

So the solution is in file `CustomeSpnegoAuthenticator.java`, change override function from `authenticate` to `doAuthenticate`. And because of this line: `formAuthenticator.setLandingPage("/home");`. In file `login.jsp`, action should be `home/j_security_check`.